# TeX Live 2011: Can I still update it to its final (frozen) state?

Tags: texlive, ctan

I wish to know that if I download TeX Live 2011 from TUG today in April 2013 and then try to update the packages from CTAN, will I get the last packages that were frozen for the 2011 year for TeX Live?

I have the final (frozen) state of TeX Live 2011 on a computer and this version has served me well. Now I wish to have the same installation (with the same versions of the packages) on a different computer.

Comment: In my opinion this will be difficult. Why? Although packages are versioned, they are not specific to a distribution's release version. I would theorize that your best bet would be to identify the frozen date for TL 2011, and match that with packages in a historical package database (see [Historical, stable version archive of packages](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31886/5764)) *manually*. Good luck.

Comment: @ Werner. Ok. What if I install the TeXLive 2011 on the new computer and then overwrite the texlive directory with the one from my old computer which has the latest packages for year 2011? And then I can refresh the TeXLive database on the new machine. 1 vote up.

Comment: That *should* work.

Comment: Off Topic:As per your question [multiple TeXLive installations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6521/15717) have both in future if needed. I suggest to be in _Sync_ without any time lag. [Update often](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437) and subscribe to [ctan RSS feeds](http://www.mail-archive.com/ctan-ann@dante.de/maillist.xml). [most used old packages can be dowloaded as tds.zip or .sty](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20160/15717) and made available to all `.tex` files.

Comment: @ texenthusiast Thanks for the information. Sometimes I wish to stick to a distribution of some point in time when I am working on a big project. But it makes sense to have multiple distributions so that I can always update one of them continuously. 1 vote up.

Comment: Why don't you simply copy the whole directory, add the path to the binaries to the path variable on the new pc and recreate the lsr-files?

Comment: @ Ulrike Fisher. Thanks. Perhaps you are right and it is the easier way. I just need to add the path to that TexLive to the path variable in Windows and put it first if I want to use that distribution instead of others. I was thinking installing the TexLive first and then overwrite it with a more recent version of the TeXLive distribution of that year as it will save the initial installation settings as well. 1 vote up.

Comment: @yCalleecharan The method shouldn't be different from the one outlined in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49936/how-to-move-tex-live-to-another-partition-data But it could be improper if Windows is involved. Give a try.

Comment: @ egreg. Thanks. I think that I would prefer to install the distribution first, overwrite the texlive folder afterwards with the most recent version of the distribution and then execute a *texhash*. I have to try it. 1 vote up.

Comment: You will have problems updating your just-installed TL2011 from the net, as probably most (all?) update-servers won't serve updates form TL2011 anymore. So your best bet likely is to install TL2011 and then copy the TL2011 directory from the running to the new computer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have problems updating your just-installed TL2011 from the net, as probably most (all?) update-servers won't serve updates for TL2011 anymore. So your best bet is to install TL2011 from the DVD (obviously not from the net) and then copy the TL2011 directory from the running installation to the new computer. If you use Unix, you can skip the installation and copy the TL2011 directory and adapt `$PATH` etc.

Comment: Thank you. I installed a fresh iso file on the new Windows machine, renamed the *2011* folder it to something else and then put the folder of the most recent version of TL2011 that I have from my old computer. A *texhash* is necessary afterwards. 1 vote up.